# HAProxy no passing headers with HTTPS

Tags: load-balancing, https, haproxy

I've have a problem that is burning my neurons for some weeks, I have a HAProxy LB + 2 Web servers. The idea is to be able to know the real IP of the computer that hit the haproxy node, for that I have the following configuration:

```
LB : 10.0.0.1 - haproxy.example.test
Web1 : 10.0.0.2 - web1.example.test
Web2 : 10.0.0.3 - web2.example.test
```

The certificate is on each of the web nodes and it is working ok with the exception of the headers not being passed.

haproxy.cfg

```
global
   log /dev/log local0
   log /dev/log local1 notice
   chroot /var/lib/haproxy
   stats timeout 30s
   user haproxy
   group haproxy
   daemon

defaults
   log global
   option forwardfor
   option httplog
#   option dontlognull
   timeout connect 5000
   timeout client 50000
   timeout server 50000

frontend http_front
   bind *:80
   stats uri /haproxy?stats
   default_backend http_back

frontend https_front
   bind *:443
   default_backend https_back

backend http_back
   balance roundrobin
   mode http
   http-request add-header X-CLIENT-IP %[src]
   http-request set-header X-Request-Start t=%Ts%ms
   server web1 10.0.0.2:80 check
   server web2 10.0.0.3:80 check

backend https_back
   balance roundrobin
   mode tcp
   option forwardfor
   http-request set-header X-Forwarded-Port %[dst_port]
   http-request add-header X-Forwarded-Proto https if { ssl_fc }
   http-request set-header X-Forward-For %[src]
   http-request add-header X-CLIENT-IP %[src]
   http-request set-header X-Request-Start t=%Ts%ms
   server webs1 10.0.0.2:443 check
   server webs2 10.0.0.3:443 check
```

If I access the 10.0.0.1 (haproxy.example.test) using HTTP I get the 
expected headers:

```
HTTP_X_CLIENT_IP    65.28.121.161
HTTP_X_REQUEST_START    t=1557918661669
HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR    65.28.121.161
```

But if I access with HTTPS none of those headers are passed to Apache...

I've tried eveything and can't figure this out, googled for weeks without success. Anyone has an idea why is this happening?

**UPDATE**:

Thank you for guiding me in the righ path, the solution passed for the configuration bellow:

```
global
   log /dev/log local0
   log /dev/log local1 notice
   chroot /var/lib/haproxy
   stats timeout 30s
   user haproxy
   group haproxy
   daemon

defaults
   log global
   option forwardfor
   option httplog
   option dontlognull
   timeout connect 5000
   timeout client 50000
   timeout server 50000


frontend localhost
    bind *:80
    bind *:443 ssl crt /etc/haproxy/haproxy.crt
    mode http
    redirect scheme https if !{ ssl_fc }
    default_backend nodes

backend nodes
    mode http
    balance roundrobin
    option forwardfor
    option httpchk HEAD / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost:localhost
    server web01 10.0.0.2:80 check
    server web02 10.0.0.3:80 check
    http-request set-header X-Forwarded-Port %[dst_port]
    http-request add-header X-Forwarded-Proto https if { ssl_fc }
```

HAProxy will negociate the secure connection and pass the traffic as http, instead of https, to the web servers.

It was based in this nice article https://serversforhackers.com/c/using-ssl-certificates-with-haproxy

Cheers,

Hugo Ferreira

Comment: To be able to modify the HTTPS requests your HAproxy instance needs to be able to decrypt the HTTPS requests.  In other words: you need to install and configure the TLS certificates for the domain(s) you loadbalance on the server running HAproxy so it can decrypt incoming requests, add the headers, and then make new https requests to your back-end servers.

Comment: I believe you need to add `option forwardfor` in the frontend, not the backend. Strange that you get X-Forwarded-For on HTTP, as you don't set that header in the HTTP path. Have you pasted the correct version of haproxy.conf?

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. Yes, it is the correct config. I have this in several clusters working like a charm, but what you say makes sense. I'm gonna configure the HAProxy with the certificates to see if the problem is solved.

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer and accept it. Otherwise the question is not marked as "solved" in the system and will pop up again and again.

Answer (score 0):

Final config

```
   log /dev/log local0
   log /dev/log local1 notice
   chroot /var/lib/haproxy
   stats timeout 30s
   user haproxy
   group haproxy
   daemon

defaults
   log global
   option forwardfor
   option httplog
   option dontlognull
   timeout connect 5000
   timeout client 50000
   timeout server 50000


frontend localhost
    bind *:80
    bind *:443 ssl crt /etc/haproxy/haproxy.crt
    mode http
    redirect scheme https if !{ ssl_fc }
    default_backend nodes

backend nodes
    mode http
    balance roundrobin
    option forwardfor
    option httpchk HEAD / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost:localhost
    server web01 10.0.0.2:80 check
    server web02 10.0.0.3:80 check
    http-request set-header X-Forwarded-Port %[dst_port]
    http-request add-header X-Forwarded-Proto https if { ssl_fc }
```

HAProxy will negociate the secure connection and pass the traffic as http, instead of https, to the web servers.

It was based in this nice article https://serversforhackers.com/c/using-ssl-certificates-with-haproxy